# vim with plugin vim-flutter using command :FlutterRun and emulator Genymotion produces an error

Tags: flutter, vim, genymotion

Using the "vim-flutter" plugin when I run ": FlutterRun" I get the following error message (I use as emulator "Genymotion"):

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.

```
 build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3

 platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in Vim or `vim-flutter` plugin. You can accept licenses for SDKs from console:

```sh
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: Are you have installed Android Studio?

Comment: ,when I run it:

transistor47@hobbit:~/app/genymotion$ flutter doctor --android-licenses 

I get the following answer 

Android sdkmanager tool not found (/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
detailed instructions.


As I had an installation problem, I always have to run as root. My folder is the following:

/ root / Android / Sdk / tools / bin / sdkmanager

Comment: You need to install Android SDK to your user directory and follow recommendations from install tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to delete the file "disabled_plugins.txt" from
~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1

After I executed "flutter config --android-sdk "

It works!!!!